# how to paginate a table in zend framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pagination

I'm using zend framework and want to paginate the table of contents based on the data received from the MySQL table. I want to show only 10 rows in the html table.

here is the .phtml code i have..

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            if(isset($this->ErrorMessage))
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>" . $this->ErrorMessage . "</div>";
                            if(isset($this->success))
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . $this->success . "</div>";
                            echo $this->form;
                        ?>

                        <!-- / .table -->
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                              <table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable table-bordered no-footer" role="grid">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>

                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php if(isset($this->results)) { ?>
                                    <?php foreach($this->results as $result) { ?>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $result->id; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result->name; ?></td>

                                  </tr>
                                  <?php } ?>
                                  <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

so how can i add the pagination...

Comment: Are you working on ZF1 or ZF2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state whether you want to paginate on the client or server side. If you want to paginate on the client side, the easiest way is to just use JQuery DataTables:

https://www.datatables.net/

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataTable').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to use `Paginator` class. Let' say that you already have a factory class which passess an instance of tablegateway adapter to your modeltable class. Let's create a function to retreive all the data

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $dbSelect = new DbSelect($select, $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(), $this->tableGateway->getResultSetPrototype());
    return new Paginator($dbselect);
}
```

In your controller you will do something simillar to this.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->setTemplate("application/index/index");
    $paginator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("myModelTable")->fetchAll();
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $this->params("page", 1));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    return $this->view;
}
```

In your view part put this somewhere (usually at the bottom of the file)

```
echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'sliding', 'application/pagination.phtml', ['route' => 'application']);
```